# Ethernet/IP - is it possible to read/write specific data from Assembly Object using Get/Set_Attribute_Single and Extended Logical Format?

Tags: plc

We have a Windows application that we are using to test against a CLICK PLC and a Schneider PLC.

My question is around reading and writing data to the Assembly Object, and more specifically if there is a way to read/write from/to a particular spot in the byte array defined by the Assembly Object instance?

Reading the entire array is not so much of an issue, but we really don't want to write the entire array if all we need to do is write a single value. If we have to write all the values back, don't we risk overwriting some values that could have changed underneath us? Yes, we could do a read, change the single value, then write, but there's is no guarantee that the other values won't have changed between the read and the write.

The PLCs do not support Get/Set_Member, so we cannot use that, which means we are left with Get/Set_Attribute_Single. From looking at the ODVA documentation, Vol 1, Appendix C, section C-1.4.2 it seems to me that I can create an EPATH that should let me do just that by using the Extended Logical Format?

Ex: If I want to read the first element in the byte array, I should be able to construct my padded EPATH using the Extended Logical Format as follows:

EPATH = 20 04 | 24 65 | 30 03 | 3D 01 | 00 00
(Class ID 4, Instance ID 101, Attribute 3, Extended Logical with 16 bit Logical value and Array Index Type, Array Index 0)

If I call Get_Attribute_Single with this EPATH I get a "Path Segment Error" for either PLC.

1. Is my thinking correct, that I should be able to get an array element?
2. If so, is my EPATH correct?
3. If so, could the error be due to either PLC not supporting this?